# What does an icon that looks like a pair of connected chain links next to a wireless network name mean?

Tags: network, wifi

When I click on the WiFi symbol in the menu bar on my Mac I get a list of wireless networks, most of them with little lock icons next to them. But some of them show what looks like a pair of chain links instead (see image below). What does this mean? That these networks are personal hotspots?

[image: WiFi icons]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a personal hotspot created by an iOS device to share the cellular data connection that the phone has over Wi-Fi.

Comment: The symbol also appears with bluetooth and USB hotspots.

Comment: @grgarside, agreed, but can you explain what it means technically?  Are there capabilities that it offers that a standard wireless hotspot or access point does not?

Comment: From what I can gather, it's a designated icon to tell users that the device is running an Apple OS (OSX, MacOS, iOS) which offers a broader-use hotspot feature which may range from Bluetooth, USB and Wifi hotspot capabilities.  It appears to be a brand-specific designation to help the person connecting know the tether capabilities are NOT limited to only wifi.

Comment: It's not limited to iOS: I also get this icon when I use my Android device as a hotspot (Mi Mix 2).

Comment: Not just iOS devices. I get it on a Xiaomi hotspot