# What does the link symbol mean in the Wi-Fi network list on iOS?

Tags: ios, wifi

What does the "link" ([image]) mean in the Wi-Fi network list on iOS?

Example (see red rectangle):

[image]

Comment: A much closer duplicate might be https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141565/what-does-an-icon-that-looks-like-a-pair-of-connected-chain-links-next-to-a-wire but I chose to link to the more technical discussion on how this icon is detected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means it's not a regular WiFi, it's a computer-to-computer network. In this case, it means that your the Wifi network host is an iPhone sharing itself as a Hotspot and other properties may be available.

See also [this Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681#hotspot).

> For personal hotspot on iPhone 8 or earlier, you can also see how many devices joined your Hotspot.
>
> [image: personal hotspot icon]